# Why isn't params being read properly?

Tags: ruby, detect, parameters

When I try to run this in one of my controllers:

`goal = @user.goals.detect{|g| g.id == params[:id]}`

goal gets set to nil. The thing is, I've run `puts params[:id]` before this line and it output `112`. So I plugged 112 into the detect in place of params[:id] and it worked fine. I don't understand why params[:id] isn't being read 'as 112', which is what puts outputs. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `params[:id]` is going to be a string, and it's likely that your `g.id` is an integer. While they will both print the same, they are not equal:

```
>> "112" == 112
=> false
>> puts "112"
112
=> nil
>> puts 112
112
=> nil
```

You should probably convert your parameter to an integer before comparing it:

```
goal = @user.goals.detect{|g| g.id == params[:id].to_i}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess `params[:id]` equals to '112' (string), not 112 (integer).

Try this:

```
goal = @user.goals.detect{|g| g.id == params[:id].to_i}
```